# Get Lists from webid

Tags: list, javascript

This is my Code to get Lists by url:

```
this.getListsOfWebByUrl = function (Url) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(Url);
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        var collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

        clientContext.load(collList, 'Include(Title , Id)');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSucc(sender, args) {
            var listInfo = new Object();
            listInfo.title = new Array();
            listInfo.id = new Array();
            listInfo.url = new Array();
            listInfoCollection = collList.getEnumerator();
            while (listInfoCollection.moveNext()){
                var oList = listInfoCollection.get_current();
                listInfo.title.push(oList.get_title());
                listInfo.id.push(oList.get_id()._m_guidString$p$0);
                listInfo.url.push(collList.get_item('url'));
            }
            return listInfo;
        }, function onFail(sender, args) {
            alert("request Failed: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        });

    }
```

now I want to do the same but with webId instead of url , But I have no Idea on how to do this . 
Thanks for your help

Comment: the 2 search words that gets you a massive load of Documentation are ``Enumerate`` and ``SPWeb``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following, I hope ClientContext accept Web id as parameter.

```
var guid = "00000-00000-00000-00000-00000-00000"
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(guid);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.